# $f$ is Continuously Differentiable $\Rightarrow \exists f^{-1}$

Tags: derivatives, continuity, inverse-function

following is the **inverse function theorem**:

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a function which is continusoly differentiable at $a \in X$ and $f(a) \neq 0$. Then $\exists f'^{-1}(a)$ and $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at $x=a$ and $f^{-1}(f(a)) = {1\over f'(a)}$

Question: How could one prove that "continuity and differentibility guarantees the existence of inverse mapping"?

Comment: Slow down! You have asked 4 questions in one hour interval ! Take time to work these questions by yourself...

Comment: @JeanMarie you're right. will follow your guidance

Comment: Answer: No one can, because it is not true.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli "if f is a continuously differentiable function with nonzero derivative at the point a, then f is invertible.." this is the wikipedia excerpt

Comment: @Daschin ...which is neither what was written, nor what is *currently* written.

Comment: you should check your analysis book, such theorem usually comes after implicit function theorem

Comment: @jack 46 will do.

Comment: Er, for others who may be confused, I think Sassatelli's second comment is wrt to what your question has written, not what wikipedia has written (or you quoted). His first comment is absolutely correct though. Do you see the difference between your statement and wikipedia's?

Comment: Not yet.. trying to figure out though @user365807